# Latex worries to do with formatting

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have used latex to try and get a CV done. I used an available format online and tried to edit. The only problem I have is that the 'Employment section now starts on a new page due to lack of space in the previous page. I want to try and fit part of this section into the first page and have it continue in the next. In other words, I'd like to split a section in tabular form between two pages.

Here is the code for further info, I would appreciate any help available.
Thank you! P.S, its very clear that I am a total amateur if that! :P

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
        \usepackage{marvosym}
        \usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
        \usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
        \RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
        \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
         \usepackage[big]{layaureo}                 %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
        \usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
        \usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
        \hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
         \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
        %\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
        \setmainfont[
        SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
        BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
        ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
        {Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
       \titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
        \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
        \hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
        \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

        \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
        \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule} 
        \textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
          \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
        \begin{document}

%WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
         %\font\wm=''Baskerville:color=787878'' at 8pt
%\font\wmweb=''Baskerville:color=FF1493'' at 8pt
%{\wm 
%   \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
%       \rotatebox{-90}{\parbox{500mm}{
%           Typeset by Alessandro Plasmati with \XeTeX\  \today\ for 
%           {\wmweb \href{http://www.aleplasmati.comuv.com}{aleplasmati.comuv.com}}
%       }
%   }
%   \end{textblock}
%}

         \pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

         \font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
         \par{\centering
        {\Huge ALaan \textsc{Moses}
    }\bigskip\par}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Details
\section{Personal Details}

        \begin{tabular}{rl}
             \textsc{Address:}   & 27 Munster Avenue, Hounslow, Middlesex, TW45BG \\
        \textsc{Mobile No.:}     & 07539341262\\
            \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:alan******25@hotmail.co.uk}{alan******25@hotmail.co.uk}
        \end{tabular}

%Section: Work Experience at the top


%Section: Education
        \section{Education}
        \begin{tabular}{rl} 
         \textsc{2012}-Present&  \textbf{University of Surrey}, Guildford\\

         &MEng (Hons) \textsc{Chemical Engineering}: Predicted 2.1 \\\\
         &Modules include: Advanced Chemical and Biological Reaction Engineering,\\
         &Engineering Management and Corporate Sustainability, Energy and \\
         &Industrial Systems, Mass and Energy Balances, Heat Transfer and Applied\\
         &Thermodynamics, Process Operation and Management, and Separation\\
         &  Processes.\\\\

         \textsc{2005}-2012& \textbf{St.Mark's Catholic School}, Hounslow\\ 
         &\textsc{A-Levels}: A A B\\
         &\textsc{AS-Levels}: A A A B\\
         &\textsc{GCSEs}: 11 A*-C grades
         \end{tabular}
         \section{Relevant Work Experience}
         \begin{tabular}{r|p{10cm}}
         \textsc{April 2016} & Shift leader and worker at \textsc{The Hess Rig},       
\        emph{University of Surrey}\\&\footnotesize{Led and worked as a team in a large group of 30 to produce saline solution of a specific concentration over the duration of a week. This was done using a whole chemical process pilot.}\\\\
         \end{tabular}


         \section{Employment}
         \begin{tabular}{r|p{10cm}}
          \emph{Current} & Customer Service Assistant at 
           \textsc{Tesco}, Feltham \\\textsc{}&\emph{University of Surrey} Open day helper and Tour guide\\
           &\footnotesize{Since July 2016, both roles have been undertaken and carried forward into the Masters year. This entails:}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Working flexible hours including evenings and weekends.
              \item Using initiative to work with little or no supervision.
              \item Responding to deadlines in a rational and amicable way.
                    \newpage
              \item Demonstrating excellent team-working and leadership skills.
              \item Offering advice to customers and prospective students.
              \item Dealing with customer complaints and problems in a calm manner.
             \item Developing interpersonal and problem solving skills.
          \end{itemize}
 \\

        \textsc{April 2016} & Shift leader and worker at \textsc{The Hess Rig},         \        emph{University of Surrey}\\&\footnotesize{Led and worked as a team in a large group of 30 to produce saline solution of a specific concentration over the duration of a week. This was done using a whole chemical process pilot.}\\\\
        \textsc{June-December 2010} & Helper at Oaklands School, \textsc{Isleworth} \\
&\footnotesize{Assisted the teaching of students with learning difficulties:}
\begin{itemize}
             \item Communicated and integrated effectively with people who had visual impairments, physical disabilities and those who were emotionally challenged.
     \item The role provided an outlet to expand upon creativity.
     \item Became more effective in planning and organising.
     \item Managed classes with challenging behaviour.
     \end{itemize}\\


     \textsc{July 2009-September 2015} & Sales Assistant at \textsc{HMV, Boots, WHSmith} \\
&\footnotesize{}\begin{itemize}
     \item Actively enticed customers into purchasing optional insurance and products in order to maximise revenue.
     \item Gained a profound knowledge of products and was able to clearly convey complex details and benefits to customers.
     \item Was motivated and determined to succeed in a pressurised sales driven environment.
    \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}

\section{Computer Skills}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
 Basic Knowledge:&  \textsc{PYTHON}, \textsc{GAMS}, \textsc{MATLAB},   \textsc{CHEMCAD}, \textsc{HYSYS} \\

Intermediate Knowledge:& Endnote, Excel, Word, PowerPoint\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Interests and Activities}
Technology, Programming, Science Fiction, Reading\\
Cooking, Table Tennis, Football, Travelling

        \section{References}
        \emph{Available on Request}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: You can delete your question on Stackoverflow I've copied it here

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: @Dan \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using something that is more easily breakable across the page boundary. One such option is provided by [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}

\newenvironment{employment}
  {\columnratio{0.4}
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  }{\end{paracol}}
\newcommand{\leftcol}{%
  \switchcolumn[0]*\raggedleft\scshape}
\newcommand{\rightcol}{%
  \switchcolumn[1]\upshape\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\section{Employment}
\begin{employment}
  \leftcol
    Current
  \rightcol
    \lipsum[1]
  \leftcol
    April 2006
  \rightcol
    \lipsum[2]
  \leftcol
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c} June - \\ December 2010 \end{tabular}
  \rightcol
    \lipsum[3]
  \leftcol
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c} July 2009 - \\ September 2015 \end{tabular}
  \rightcol
    \lipsum[4]
  \leftcol
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c} August 2003 - \\ June 2009 \end{tabular}
  \rightcol
    \lipsum[5]
\end{employment}

\end{document}
```

The above `employment` environment sets up the `paracol` environment that uses only two columns. Switches `\leftcol` and `\rightcol` are used to switch between the date and description columns.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I tried to implement this but ran into numerous errors, possibly isn't compatible with the rest of the document.

Comment: I have pasted the whole code because I am a little unsure of how to implement this. 
Cheers for the help

Comment: @AlanM: So it's working?

Comment: No, not quite. I don't quite know how to apply this to the above to get the desired effect. When I try I seem to get errors.
Regards

Comment: @AlanM: See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/BdbdHqi2). I don't have the fonts you're using, so I had to comment out a bunch of stuff. However, you'll see how I changed the "Employment" section and what I placed in the preamble.